# Add page to PDF file using Powershell

Tags: powershell, pdf

I'm new here i don't have much experience in programming, except VBA.

I'm looking for an automated solution to merge pdf files. I don't even know if that's possible, i guess though. I was thinking about using the powershell to do that.

Immaging having a "file_1.pdf" (2 pages) and a "file_2.pdf" (1 page). The result should be a "file_3.pdf" containing all three pages. The page of the "file_2.pdf" should be insertet after the last page of "file_1.pdf".

Thanks in advance guys!

Sasha

Comment: https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/MergePdf/1.1/Content/MergePdf.psm1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution for this:

I used the toolkit "pdftk server" from pdflabs

[pdflabs toolkit server](https://www.pdflabs.com/tools/pdftk-server/)

Works like a charm